# '.contains' is not working in android phones but its working fine in web page

Tags: javascript

I have a productlist and i want to scarch the productlist by input parameter. so I was using `contains` for scarching the input string in the productlist. its working fine with web page. but when i open the same page in mobile web page its not working. and giving an error that 'contains' in not define.

```
if(productlist[i].name.toLowerCase().contains(input_val.toLowerCase()))

    --my business logic--
```

after that i  have tried with `indexOf` then its working fine in both cases.

```
if(productlist[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(input_val.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
    --my business logic --
```

what is the problem for .contains??

Comment: Maybe your andriod browser doesn't support the function? Just use `indexOf`. And what are you using `eval` for?

Comment: Shawn is correct, according to Mozilla, Android does not support contains. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains

Comment: .contains is a JavaScript Harmony feature (ES6/ES.next). You can create your own `contains` function however. `String.prototype.contains = function () { ... };`

Comment: i was using eval coz productlist was comming from server with different format eval change the format to string . nway thanks @JLevett

Comment: @KousikChowdhury There is never an excuse to use eval. You could use `String(productlist)` or `productlist.toString()` or if it was an object `JSON.stringify(productlist)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Polyfill, ( Reference : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains))

```
if(!('contains' in String.prototype)) {
  String.prototype.contains = function(str, startIndex) { 
      return -1 !== String.prototype.indexOf.call(this, str, startIndex); 
  };
}
```

See the [Compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/#search=contains) in Can I use...

**Update :** Also you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/method-like-string-contains-in-javascript).

Comment: @Shawn31313, Yes, definitely it's but the question is `'.contains' is not working in android phones but its working fine in web page` so answer the relevant one.